# gitolite: effective permissions per branch

Tags: permissions, gitolite

When I run `ssh git@host repo` I receive list of my permissions

It says I have RW access to entire repo , while I have RW access to all but one branch

Are there any way to view branch permissions using gitolite?

Maybe this is possible via  `admin-defined command`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got mail from gitolite author, `sitaram`

> sorry, no.  It's upto the gitolite admin to inform you what your branch
>   perms are.
>
> Implementing that would involve having to educate users about all the
>   nuances of a gitolite conf file syntax, the regular expression stuff,
>   the defaults, and God alone knows what else.
>
> I would definitely not encourage that!  It is too painful!

so admin-defined command is the only way to go. Anyone?